# Ember route with model not working on internet explorer

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a website that works perfectly on chrome; but when I try to open it with Internet Explorer, all the routes that loads a model, show an error in the console:

```
Error while loading route: undefined
```

All other routes that have no model hook to execute, works ok; I'm testing it on Internet Explorer 9;

Someone knows why this is happening?
An example of not working route:

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('product');
    }
});
```

Using:

```
LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true,
```

I can see this:

```
Transition #1: eng.products.all: calling beforeModel hook
Transition #1: eng.products.all: calling deserialize hook
Error while loading route: undefined
Transition #1: eng.products.all: transition aborted
```

Comment: You can see the issue in action also on this project already online: http://www.paesidisandalmazzo.it/  Opening it with ie9 and clicking on "Beni in rete" or "Comuni in rete" on the main menu (the only two that needs to load models), you get the error...

Comment: Another update: deleting the model hook, make the website no more crash on ie9;

Comment: does ie9 have some troubles with promises?